# Programmatically click on the button

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, button, dom-events

Button code in HTML:

```
<div class="login-new-open-button">
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-square login-new-dialog-button" ng-click="continue()" translate="">Continue</button>
</div>
```

The button can be found programmatically using Javascript:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-primary btn-square login-new-dialog-button')
```

This call doesn't work:

```
document.getElementById('btn btn-primary btn-square login-new-dialog-button').click();
```

But programmatically clicking on it does not work.

Based on the connected scripts on the page, angular 10.5.10.26529 is used.
Is it possible to use JavaScript to call a button click made in Angular?

Comment: You can't define continue as function its a keyword !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For programmatically clicking button use .click () method . Also you can't define continue ( reserved keyword ) as function in js

See example =>

**HTML**

```
<div class="login-new-open-button">
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-square login-new-dialog-button" ng-click="Continue()" translate="">Continue</button>
</div>
```

**Js**

```
  let element = document.querySelector('.btn');
  element.click()
  function Continue(){ // C is capital if small then keyword continue which isn't  possible
   alert("button clicked")
  }
```

> For selecting a particular button it is preferred to use id and getElementById method instead of class

Comment: I don't have access to change the id of the elements, this is a page that we get, not create.

Comment: @Sektor Okay , then use anything unique like tag or class

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to your button (id="niceBtn") and call it like:

```
document.getElementById('niceBtn').click();
```